# I tried to install Tortoise on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation, 22.04

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andry/Téléchargements/tortoisehg-6.6.3/./thg", line 163, in <module>
    tortoisehg.hgqt.run.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/util.py", line 247, in __getattribute__
    self.__spec__.loader.exec_module(self)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/andry/Téléchargements/tortoisehg-6.6.3/tortoisehg/hgqt/run.py", line 47, in <module>
    from tortoisehg.util.i18n import agettext, _
ImportError: cannot import name 'agettext' from 'tortoisehg.util.i18n' (/home/andry/Téléchargements/tortoisehg-6.6.3/tortoisehg/util/i18n.py)
```

I tried to install tortoise in Ubuntu 22.04 and this error appeared when I tried to install it using apt, snap and .tar.gz. I tried tortoiseHg 5.5, but I got the same error again.

Comment: mercurial version 6.6.3